# jQuery: sort a list by two params

Tags: jquery, sorting

I need to sort a list of divs by two values. In my example, the div with the shortest duration should be on top of the list. So far I got it working. BUT if I have two divs with the same duration, the sort function should have the one on top that has the shortest duration AND the lowest price.

How do I combine two of this sort functions?

The result should be:

```
Duration: 500 - Price: 190
Duration: 500 - Price: 250
Duration: 600 - Price: 100
Duration: 700 - Price: 130
```

```js
var List__fastest = "";
List__fastest = $("div");
List__fastest.sort(function (a, b) { return $(a).data("duration") - $(b).data("duration") });

$("#result").html(List__fastest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-duration="700" data-price="130">Duration: 700 - Price: 130</div>
<div data-duration="500" data-price="250">Duration: 500 - Price: 250</div>
<div data-duration="600" data-price="100">Duration: 600 - Price: 100</div>
<div data-duration="500" data-price="190">Duration: 500 - Price: 190</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `List__fastest.sort(function (a, b) { return $(a).data("duration") - $(b).data("duration") || $(a).data("price") - $(b).data("price") });`

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me! Thank you for your help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if the result of comparing the first thing you want to sort on is that they aren't equal, return that result; otherwise, return the result of doing the comparison of the second thing you want to sort on. You can do that with JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var List__fastest = "";
  List__fastest = $("div");
  List__fastest.sort(function (a, b) {
      return $(a).data("duration") - $(b).data("duration") // First by this
          || $(a).data("price") - $(b).data("price");      // Then by this
  });

  $("#result").html(List__fastest);
}, 800);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-duration="700" data-price="130">Duration: 700 - Price: 130</div>
<div data-duration="500" data-price="250">Duration: 500 - Price: 250</div>
<div data-duration="600" data-price="100">Duration: 600 - Price: 100</div>
<div data-duration="500" data-price="190">Duration: 500 - Price: 190</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Obviously, reverse the order of the comparisons if you want to sort by price first, and then duration. (Both ways end up with the lowest duration and lowest price as the first time.)

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me! Thank you for your help and the good explanation! <3